# Не удаляется последний символ python

Tags: python, удаление-символов

```
data = "password_xps.json"
with open(data, 'r+', encoding ='utf-8') as passb:
    ad = passb.read()
    ad[:-1]
    print(ad)
```

вывод:

```
  "path": [
         {
           "name": "",
           "parentId": "",
           "id": ""
         }
         ],       
         "folderId": "",
         "folderName": ""
  }, 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Ну, вы взяли срез. Но результат же надо куда то присвоить, вам так не кажется? Напишите хотя бы `ad = ad[:-1]`.

Comment: Добавил, не помогло

Comment: С чего так решили? В конце обычно есть перевод строки. Вы его удалили. Наверняка теперь при выводе в конце стало одной пустой строкой меньше.

Comment: Все проверил, решилось, спасибо

Comment: В консоли запятая удаляется, но в файле нет, в чём может быть причина?

Comment: В том, что вы не записали результат в файл, возможно?

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно есть пробел либо перенос строки после этого символа.
Я бы использовал метод `ad.strip()`, а затем уже обрезал бы последний символ. Чуть не забыл, нужно записать изменения обратно в переменную `ad = ad.strip()[:-1]`.

Пример:

```
data = "password_xps.json"
with open(data, 'r+', encoding ='utf-8') as passb:
    ad = passb.read()
    ad = ad.strip()[:-1]
    print(ad)
with open(data, 'w', encoding ='utf-8') as passb:
    passb.write(ad)
```